# Unable to Sign into Google Chrome and also unable to open some Google sites

Tags: google-chrome, google-sync, google-groups, google-plus

I'm using both Ubuntu and Windows, I'm having problems with signing into Google Chrome to sync my user data across different computers and my mobile phone (I've stopped using my phone a while ago). And oddly enough I'm also having problems accessing some Google sites, Google+ and Google Groups among others. `chrome://sync` shows the following error,

> Unrecoverable error detected at chrome/browser/sync/profile_sync_service.cc[392] OnSyncConfigureRetry : Configure failed to download.

How can I fix this?

Comment: So Chrome on both OSes is giving you the same error?

Comment: Yes, that's the case. Accessing Google+ and Google groups is also a problem. Funny enough, however, I can access them using an anonymity website. At first I was thinking that access to the website has been blocked by the ISP but I asked some other people who use the ISP and they said the sites are working for them. Just for you to know, I've cleared my user data on both computers, even re-installed chrome on my Ubuntu machine but nothing helps.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Do those work fine?

Comment: I've used Firefox, and it has the same problem. I can't view any of the web page I mentioned above.

Comment: Do you get any specific errors? Have you checked your hosts file?

Comment: In all cases here is what I get, `Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.` This is what my `/etc/hosts` file looks like: `127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 tsega-HPLP

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters`

Comment: Well, if you can use a LiveCD to browse those sites, that would confirm that there's some sort of weird issue affecting both installed OSes. Otherwise the problem most likely lies elsewhere. Might need to thoroughly check your modem/router settings etc.